# How to count PASS/FAIL results and print number of pass and fails

Tags: java, logging, counter

How can i count and print the number of FAIL and PASS tests in last column in my log file

```
boolean globalRet = true;

for (boolean anArrRet : arrRet) {
    if (!anArrRet) {
        globalRet = false; 
        break;
    }
}

if (globalRet) {
    logLine += cnd.getLineLastAll() + "PASS,NA\n";
} else {
    logLine += cnd.getLineLastAll() + "FAIL,";

    for (int i = 0; i < arrRet.length; i++) {
        if (!arrRet[i]) {
            logLine += arrCondition[i] + "&";
        }
    } 

    logLine += "\n";
}
```

Data file that im using is looks like

```
CO2, Conditions
2.0, CEC_P=NA & CPH_P=NA & C_P=NA & H_P=NA 
5.5, CNA=NA
```

There is my log file looks like as you can see in 2nd line 2 conditions was passed and 2 was failed but i don't print the passed conditions into log file

```
 CO2,  Result, Reason
  2.0   FAIL,   CEC_P=NA & CPH_P=NA
  5.5   PASS,   NA
```

So it can be more that one reason why its fail and the reasons separate by &

Now what i want to get in my logfile should looks like this

```
CO2,  Result, Reason               Passed, Failed
2.0   FAIL,   CEC_P=NA & CPH_P=NA  2,      2
5.5   PASS,   NA                   1,      0
```

Comment: Use counter variables... If you want more specific hints, recommendations and help in general, provide more information, please. Show us your code. What is a fail and what is a pass? There are very skilled users here, but none of them will be able to read your thoughts.

Comment: What is your log file? How did you attempt to solve this problem? You didn’t provide us enough information to help you.

Comment: This *comment* should have been an edit to the question. Please edit the code into your question, @Sergei. Thanks...

Comment: i edit the question now it contains more information

Answer (score 0):

if you are on a unix system the below command could do what you need (outside of java code and assuming PASS/FAIL strings are on the last column of your log file) :

```
awk '{print $NF}' your_log_file | sort | uniq -c
```

sample output :

```
  2 FAIL
  5 PASS
```

Alternatively, the below simple java code can read your file line by line and count occurrences of "FAIL" or "PASS" strings in each line and print results :

```
BufferedReader reader;
int fail = 0;
int pass = 0;            
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
          "path\\to\\your\\log_file"));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
         if (line.contains("FAIL")) fail++;
         if (line.contains("PASS")) pass++;
         line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}                
System.out.println("Number of PASS in file : " + pass);
System.out.println("Number of FAIL in file : " + fail);
```

Comment: @Sergei see updated answer for some sample java code

Comment: ive been updated the question can please take a look